# fade in/out listview header

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to implement a fading header for a list view.
I need the header to fade out when the listview is being scrolled down and fade back in when the listview is being scrolled up.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Goto YourProject-->res --> anim (make a directory named anim)
Inside it make your animation xml files
For fading in:

```
fade_in.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

For fading out:

```
fade_out.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

Now load the animations in your activity:

```
myAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_in);
myAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_out);
```

Now simply call the animation onButtonClick or any other event.

```
listViewHeader.startAnimation(myAnimation1);
```

Comment: There is no event for scrolling to the header. And i dont really need a animation i need the fade to happen while scrolling is happening.

Comment: there is listview.setOnScrollListener for that.

Comment: ask another question if you want to learn how to use listview.setOnScrollListener